# Получить изменения с другой ветки

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Есть три ветки:
main-origin
2.004.x_release
615

main-origin - главная,  2.004.x_release - создана с main-origin, 615 ветка создана с 2.004.x_release.

Задача простая: получить все изменения в ветки 2.004.x_release в 615. Для этого я делаю

```
pull main-origin 2.004.x_release
```

После чего я вижу сообщение:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in 
b2b/protected/modules/Admin/views/adminPanel/addmodule.php
Auto-merging b2b/protected/config/main.php
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Я устраняю конфликт (приняв свои изменения) и делаю push. Но проблема в том, что файлы, которые я получил, теперь показываются так, как будто я их создавал или изменил - то есть они попадают в коммит от моего имени.
Перед командой pull в git status пусто, после того как делаю git pull и устраняю конфлик, в git status появляються куча файлов которые помечены как изменины/созданные мной хотя этого я не делал.

Как это исправить?

Comment: *от моего имени* — вероятно, не файлы, а последний коммит, в котором вы внесли изменения. это нормально, разумно и соответствует действительности.

Comment: редакторовал сообщение, новерно вы не успели прочитать - " Перед командой pull в git status пусто, после того как делаю git pull и устраняю конфлик, в git status появляються куча файлов которые помечены как изменины/созданные мной хотя этого я не делал."

Comment: вы отправили (возможно, правильные, возможно, нет) коммиты в совместно используемый репозиторий. самостоятельно теперь вы их не сможете удалить. вы можете лишь добавить новые коммиты, вносящие противоположные изменения.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы делаете гит пулл, происходит коммит с мерджем, чаще всего автоматический. Когда происходит конфликт, гит помечает строки в файлах (поэтому они отображаются в статусе) и вы должны устранить конфликты.

После этого нужно завершить мердж путем создания коммита:

```
git commit
```

При этом в редакторе по умолчанию (скорее всего `vim`) откроется описание слияния и список конфликтных файлов. Сохраняете и выходите. Если это `vim` - нажимаете `ESC` потом `:` потом `x` и `Enter`, если это редактор `nano` то `Ctrl+o` потом `Ctrl+x`.

И только после коммита с мерджем:

```
git push
```

А лучше с указанием сервера удаленного и вашей ветки, в которую мерджили:

```
git push origin 615
```